# Auto-update a strURL string from a cell in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, download, zip, auto-update

I download zip files from a statisics website each month. I have an excel vba macro that will download the file for me but the location changes each month.
For instance. The latest data might be found at
strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/Jan-2023/Time-Series.zip"
but next month it will be
strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/feb-2023/Time-Series.zip"

The data is usually at least one month old so the current date won't work. This is why I wanted to link to a cell with the date of the data, not the current date.

If possible I want the macro to get the new address from a cell in the workbook so I can simply update a single cell date value rather than code in the macro each month

Below is the macro I am using

```
Sub DownloadRetailTrade()
Dim strURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String
Dim DownloadStatus As Long



strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/Jan-2023/Time-Series.zip"

LocalFilePath = "D:\Data\Time-Series.zip"
DownloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, LocalFilePath, 0, 0)
If DownloadStatus = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File Downloaded. Check in this path: " & LocalFilePath
Else
    MsgBox "Download File Process Failed"
End If
Call UnZipMe
End Sub
```

I have a concatenate function in my workbook that creates the new URL when I update the date. I just haven't been able to figure out how to get my code to pick up the new URL each month.
At the moment I go into the code and change it. I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If your regional settings are english, you could do:

```
strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/" & Format(Date, "mmm") & "-2023/Time-Series.zip"
```

This will take the current month's name from today's date and add it in the string. So if you executed today, it will return:

```
https://www.statistics/retail-trade/mar-2023/Time-Series.zip
```

And in 2024 it will change, so the correct solution would be:

```
strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/" & Format(Date, "mmm-yyyy") & "/Time-Series.zip"
```

If you don't have english settings and the name of your months are different (mine are spanish, as example) the above code won't work! You need to calculate the month and then get the initials in english:

```
Dim MonthArray As Variant

MonthArray = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/" & MonthArray(Month(Date) - 1) & Format(Date, "-yyyy") & "/Time-Series.zip"
```

Please notice I'm using `Date` in the code but this can be replaced with any date you wish (a cell or whatever).

Comment: The date in the URL is never the current date but the date of the data release. So often it will be at least a month behind and sometimes up the 3 months behind.

Comment: As I said at the end of my answer, *Please notice I'm using Date in the code but this can be replaced with any date you wish (a cell or whatever).*

Comment: How would I replace Date with a cell in a workbook?

Comment: I got it working by using by replacing this
strURL = "https://www.statistics/retail-trade/Jan-2023/Time-Series.zip"
with this
strURL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
And changing the sheet name and cell as required